# How to implement a proper layer separation in XPages (i.e. talk to Java objects, not DominoViews and DominoDocuments)

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to implement a proper layer separation in my XPage project. Ideally I'm trying to get to a point where the XML in the XPage contains no SSJS and uses only EL to access Java objects.

So far I've worked out how to load all my data from the domino database into Java Beans (where 1 document = 1 Object, more or less), I'm reading view contents into Java Maps or Lists, and I've managed to display the content of these collections in repeat controls.

What I'm unsure of is how to display the content of a 'form', of a single document, without referencing the domino document. In particular, I'm unsure of how to deal with the 'new document' case. I suppose I create an empty object, then set that object as a data source for the Xpage.

I'm aware that I have to **use a ObjectDataSource for this, but I'm unsure where to actually store it**. I read an article from Stephan Wissel stating that one shouldn't put them in managed bean, so where can I put it? In one of the scoped variables like viewScope?

Right now I've written an 'ApplicationBean' which is a session-scope Managed Bean where I'm storing all my objects.

What is the best practise? It seems that there are many different ways to meet that goal. Currently I'm exploring Christian Güdemann's XPages Toolkit, which sounds very promising. I know that Samir Pipalia, John Daalsgard and Frank van der Linden have worked up their own frameworks.

So how should I go about it? Any pitfalls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a large topic indeed. As Paul mentioned, Tim's document model classes are a great example of how to do that clearly, and Tim goes into more detail in later episodes in that NotesIn9 series. My own Framework's model objects are fairly similar, though I also added [collection managers](https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/building-an-app-with-the-frostillic.us-framework--part-1) to handle the dirty business of accessing views. For better or for worse, almost every XPage developer solves this problem in a unique way.

There are a number of ways you can go about implementing this sort of thing, and some of the differences aren't terribly important in normal cases (for example, whether you preload all data from the document when constructing the model object or do lazy fetching to the back-end only as needed), but there are definitely a couple overarching questions to tackle.

#### Model Access

As you mentioned in the question, one of the big problems is how you actually access model objects from the XPage - how the objects are fetched from the DB or created anew. My Framework's model objects use a conceit of "Manager" objects, which are application-scoped beans that allow getting either named collections (which map to views), model objects by UNID, or a new model object via the keyword "new". Generally, these models (which are Serializable) are then stored in the view scope of the page using them either via `<xp:dataContext/>`, `<xe:objectData/>`, or the Framework's own `<ff:modelObjectData/>`.

I've found it very wise to avoid using managed beans to represent individual objects (like "CurrentWhatever" that you then fill with data on each page), since that muddies up your faces-config in the best case or runs into session problems in the worst (if you put it in session scope, which I rarely use).

How you implement "new" vs. "fetched" model objects depends largely on the tack you take to write your models in the first place, but most boil down to having two constructors: one to take a UNID (at least) to point to existing document and one to create a new one. If you go the "write every properly explicitly in the object with getters and setters" route, the latter would also initialize all of the fields with default values instead of reading them from a document. Internally, you should have fields to store the UNID of the document, which can indicate whether it's new or not - then, your save method can check if this field is empty and create a new document if needed (and then store the new doc's UNID in the field).

#### Views

It sounds like you're already reading your model collections into `List`s, which is good. One down side there, though, is scalability: with small (less than 100) collections, you're likely to not run into any load-speed problems, but afterwards things are going to slow down on initial page load as your code reads in the entire view ahead of time. You can mitigate this somewhat with [efficient view reading](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/17.01.2013085308KLEB9S.htm), but there's a limit. The built-in views are generally speedy because they only load data as needed (they also cheat like hell to do so, but that's another issue).

This is a noble goal to aim for yourself, but doing so to cover all cases is [no small feat](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/blob/748443fb92cf4d98da279bf7dbc4539d8c9bdde0/frostillicus.framework/frostillicus.framework.plugin/src/frostillicus/xsp/model/domino/DominoModelList.java#L71): you end up running into questions of FT searching, column resorting, efficient data preloading (you don't want to re-open the View object only to read in one entry at a time, but you also don't want to read the whole thing), use in `viewPanel` and maybe others (which require specialized interfaces), expanding/collapsing categories, and so forth. It's a [large sub-topic on its own](https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/C6E38428D404C2F285257D1B0049B129).

#### Esoterica

You're also liable to run across other areas that are more difficult than you'd think at first, such as "proper" rich text handing and file attachments. Attachments, in particular, require [direct conflict with the XSP framework](https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/how-i-added-file-download-support-to-my-model-framework) to get to function properly with custom model objects and the standard upload/download controls.

Case-sensitivity in field names is another potential area of trouble. If you're writing getters and setters for all of your fields, it's a moot point, but if you're going the "thin wrapper" route (which I prefer), it's important to code any intermediary caches/lookups in a way that deal with the fact that "FOO" and "foo" are (basically) the same as item names to Notes, but are distinct in Java. The tack I take is to make [extensive use of `TreeMap`s](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/blob/748443fb92cf4d98da279bf7dbc4539d8c9bdde0/frostillicus.framework/frostillicus.framework.plugin/src/frostillicus/xsp/model/domino/AbstractDominoModel.java#L36): if you pass `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` as the parameter to the constructor, it handles treating Strings as generally case-insensitive when used as keys.

Having your model objects work with all the standard controls like that may or may not be a priority - I find it very valuable, so I did a lot of legwork to make it happen with my framework, but if you're just going to do some basic Strings-and-numbers models, you don't necessarily need to worry.

---

So... yeah, it's a big topic! Depending on how confident you are with Java and the XPages undergirdings, I would suggest either going the route of fairly-simple "beans with getters and setters" for your objects or by looking into the implementation details of one of the existing frameworks (my own or the ones you mentioned). Sadly, there are a lot of little things that will crop up as your code gets more complicated, many of which are non-obvious to deal with.

Comment: Jesse, many many thanks for your comprehensive answer. Loads of different trails to follow. I'm really trying to learn how to do this the right way. Out of the box XPages invites you to create unmaintainable messes IMHO. I winced when you said 'I've found it very wise to avoid using managed beans to represent individual objects' - right now I have a single managedBean, 'ApplicationBean', which has private members for 'currentCourse', 'currentRegistration'. Etc. I'm still unsure as to where these should be stored.

Comment: I'm also not hell-bent on bending everything so that it is 'pure' - As you say, there are some elements such as the DataView which I find elegantly implemented. But when it comes to data manipulation, I really want to have everything in a single place, where I can test it and debug it (eventually in a separate Eclipse session). Having spent a lot of my time refactoring Notes Client applications by removing code out of buttons and hotspots, form events, I don't want to start the same story again by squirrelling some code in SSJS directly in the XML. No way José!

Comment: what's the 'thin wrapper' route?

Comment: The core trouble with any session-based state is that it's easy to run into problems with multiple tabs, different browsers, and context when a user bookmarks a page. Sometimes it's needed, but as much as possible I like to include important context in the URL (UNIDs, for example) and then load up models in the view scope of the page.

Comment: There's a lot involved on a number of topics - if you'd like, shoot me an email at jesse@frostillic.us and we can hash some stuff out. I've found that there are usually useful blog posts that come out of conversations like that.

Comment: Very thorough answer, Jesse, so I'll send mine to the bin :-)  However, there is one thing that I'll mention. I do use Session scoped managed beans - with a short timeout and keepalive as needed. I have written a little more about this here: http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/tuning-your-xpages/

Comment: Session scope definitely has its uses - I don't think it's always considered harmful. I just think it gets too much use, and apps that rely on it for user and navigation state can get very brittle.

Comment: Awww John, I was secretly hoping for an answer from you. :-).

Comment: Jesse, thankyou for the kind offer. My memory buffer is currently overloaded and I don't know which path to take first. Give me a couple of days to process this all!

Answer (score 2):

Jesse Gallagher's Scaffolding framework also accesses Java objects rather than dominoDocument datasources. I've used (and modified) Tim Tripcony's Java objects in his "Using Java in XPages series" from NotesIn9 (the first is [episode 132](http://www.notesin9.com/2013/12/17/notesin9-132-using-java-in-xpages-part-1/). The source code for what he does is on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/timtripcony/howyabean). This basically converts the dominoDocument to a Map. It doesn't cover MIME  (Rich Text) or attachments. If it's useful, I can share the amendments I made (e.g. making field names all the same case, to ensure it still works for existing documents, where fields may have been created with LotusScript).

Answer (score 0):

Andrew - Jesse's one of the experts here so I'd read his response carefully.

What I do is I took one of the key pieces of Jesses bigger framework - the "pageControllers" and I use that HEAVILY.  So I end up with a Java Class for each XPages to act as the controller.  "All" Jesse's page controller framework does is make it a little easier to consume.  So you can reference it on each page as "controller" and don't nee dot make individual managed beans for them.

I still will use SOMES SSJS on the XPage if I really need to for things like button events..  some methods that don't have proper getters and setters..  HashMap.size() for instance.  But the vast bulk of the code goes into the Java Class.  No real need for viewScope variables any more as well.

in the case of a "New Document"..  In the controller I'll create a new Java Object that represents the "Current document". I'll bind all the fields to that.  If it's new I create a new Object and assign it to the private variable.  If I'm loading form somewhere then I take that variable and load the document I want.

I've started to really try and detail this in more recent NotesIn9's.  Especially the little series on Java for Xpages developers.  I think I got far enough there to show you what you need to know.  I do plan on doing a lot more on this topic as soon as I can.

Comment: David, my brain has gone in buffer overflow right now. I'll have a look at your videos, thanks for the tip.